# Is this question SEO spam?

Tags: discussion, spam, seo

I honestly can't tell but it feels like it is link bait for health supplements.

[Like Button Width Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366206/like-button-width-not-working-causes-browser-horizontal-scrolling)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not allowed.  Whenever you see people asking

> Hey, here's my website [http://cheapv14gra,com](http://www.example.com) please debug something for me

please flag for moderator attention.

Comment: sorry I didn't find it. http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy where?

Comment: thanks! wasn't sure.  looked better than most spam websites, threw me off.

Comment: @genesis-φ - "Spam. Users that do not publish meaningful content, **use deceptive means to generate revenue or traffic**, or whose primary purpose is affiliate marketing, will be suspended."

Comment: @genesis-: It isn't *just* spam.  Its also NARQ and Too Localized.  "Debug my program for me" isn't an acceptable question.  The user *did* provide some other detail, but they relied on the user to go to their website to understand what is going on.  As soon as his websites are changed (or more likely taken over by squatters) the question becomes useless.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, precisely what flag should we use? Isn't **It is spam** a bit strong for "debug my website for me"?

Comment: @Chris: You can flag and leave a note, or "it is not welcome" is fine too

Answer (score 2):

Good spot, but it feels to me more like this is a legitimate question from a programmer who works for that company and was too lazy to remove identifying information from what might be proprietary code.  At one whole question, we can afford to allow this for now, but if we see more from the same user you might have something.

Now, whether the company itself also conducts some shady or spammy marketing...

Answer (score 1):

SEO Spam? You mean if OP is making backlinks? No, not in any case.

```
<a href="http://www.removed.com" rel="nofollow">Spam link</a>
```

if you still didn't spot it, there is `rel="nofollow"` which disallows follow that link by crawlers

Comment: Doesn't mean they aren't getting benefits from it.  It still feels spammy to Stack Overflow and the question didn't really seem real (I didn't see the bug he was talking about).

Comment: @Off I do not think programmers would like this kind of things.But yes, it is suspicious